# I Can't Play My MPD File After Packaging it with Bento4 (Dash.js Error 25)

Tags: html, mpeg-dash, dash.js, bento4

I have this MPD file created using Bento4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> <MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" minBufferTime="PT4.23S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT2M22.225S" type="static">   <!-- Created with Bento4 mp4-dash.py, VERSION=2.0.0-639 -->   <Period>
    <!-- Video -->
    <AdaptationSet mimeType="video/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" maxWidth="1920" maxHeight="1080">
      <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="4233" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
      <Representation id="video/avc1" codecs="avc1.640028" width="1920" height="1080" scanType="progressive" frameRate="24000/1001" bandwidth="3317595"/>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <!-- Audio -->
    <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="en">
      <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="4233" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
      <Representation id="audio/en/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="130559" audioSamplingRate="44100">
        <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>   </Period> </MPD>
```

I uploaded it to my server and unfortunately I'm getting video unavailable message.

I am using this player https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/latest/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html.

Hoping for your response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the mimeType of your video AdaptationSet set to "application/dash+xml"? That is the mimetype for DASH manifests. The correct mimetype should be "video/mp4". Usually the AdaptationSet carries a contentType="video" attribute instead of mimeType and the audio adaptation Set carries contentType="audio". Check out some of the sample manifests in that dash.js reference player to see examples of well-formed manifests.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to set it back to "video/mp4". It was "video/mp4" before posting it but still unable to play. Let set it back to "video/mp4". Thank you.